# Xcode 6 not showing any simulators

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode6

Downloaded Xcode 6 and I don't have any option to archive. 
[image]

Comment: Why would you use Xcode 6?... the latest is currently 7.1

Comment: Download the latest Xcode from the AppStore.  Do not use versions of Xcode that have not been downloaded direct from Apple.

Comment: I have to built the project using iOS 8 SDK.

Comment: @SwiftHipster you can set the deployment target to iOS 8.0 in Xcode 7.1 and it will do what you need.

Comment: Well deployment target and target SDK are different. My requirement is to use 8 SDK to build the project.

Answer (score 1):

Click on the project name (Right to the Run button). Three options will appear.

```
Edit scheme
New scheme
Manage scheme
You can click on "New scheme" and then click on "OK" in popup window.
```

You will have simulators list back.

> Second Option

```
Open Xcode
Go to the menu Xcode > Open Developer Tool > iOS Simulator
Even if an error dialog shows up, you still would have access to the iOS Simulator's menu
Select Hardware > Device > Manage Devices
Add (if missing) all the devices that you want, or delete and recreate the ones malfunctioning.
```

(You can check the devices at ~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices).

Comment: please accept as answer..if helped my answer

Comment: Right to to run button nothing appears in Xcode. You can see in the image. That is the problem.